# Remove useless timzone from function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-trigger

I have postgresql function that receive date variable, then I trunc day from time, but timezone anyway added to final query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.request_user_track()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        PERFORM pg_notify('user_log_added', '{"userID": ' || NEW."userID" || ',"time":"' || NEW.time || '"}');

     INSERT INTO "UserTracks"("userID", "day", "requestedAt", "createdAt", "updatedAt")
       VALUES(NEW."userID", date_trunc('day', NEW."time" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'), NOW() + interval '1 second', NOW(), NOW())
       ON CONFLICT("userID", "day") DO UPDATE SET "requestedAt" = EXCLUDED."requestedAt"
       WHERE "UserTracks"."userID" = NEW."userID" AND "UserTracks".day = date_trunc('day', NEW."time" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$function$
;
```

I try to set timezone, but anyway in final query I have in db: 2019-12-30 03:00:00

Comment: What is the column type of `UserTracks.day` and which timezone are you in (or your computer set to)? It may be that the db stored it at UTC with time 00:00:00, but when displayed is in client machine timezone.

Comment: @karmakaze type of day is timestamptz and input is timestamptz. In db it stored in MSK (+3).

Answer (score 0):

You could change your session timezone or simply `variable::timestamp` or `SELECT variable AT TIME ZONE 'desirable_timezone'`. If you only want the date, then `DATE(variable)`.  It will depend on what you want to achieve, but all methods are valid for querying or modifing your table, with or without date_trunc.

SELECT date_trunc('day',date(now()))

Comment: I am trying NEW."time"::timestamp, but anyway +3 hours added.

Comment: What result gives you after ```SELECT date_trunc('day',now())```

Comment: And if you change the session timezone? ```SET TIME ZONE 'xxx'```

Comment: yes, and then change timezone its return 2019-12-30 00:00:00

Comment: Ok, so, what is the expected result? something like '2019-12-30 00:00:00'? Because if you do not need hours then simply type date(). Edited answer.

Comment: i cant change type of column, because db in production mode. If i make date(NEW."time") it will be autoconverted to timestampz?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, given that the type of `day` is `timestamptz` in the db '2019-12-30 03:00:00' stored at MSK (+3) timezone, I believe the database is doing the right thing.

If you think about it, '2019-12-30 03:00:00 +03:00' is the same time as '2019-12-30 00:00:00 +00:00'. Now we just want the same timestamp to be stored at UTC timezone.

I have a hunch, try something like:

```
INSERT INTO "UserTracks"("userID", "day", ...)
       VALUES(NEW."userID", date_trunc('day', NEW."time" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', ...)
```

It may be the case the result of date_trune() isn't kept at UTC timezone.

The other thing to note is that if this is deployed to a production server configured to run its OS and PostgreSQL in UTC (generally recommended) these issues won't exist.

Comment: I am trying ... AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ... before, its not working. Strange things because all dates stored in MSK (+3) and input in MSK (+3), but then i do date_trunc this add 3 hours, not change timezone, just add additional hours. I fix it by: date_trunc('day', NEW."time") - interval '3 hour', but its bad fix :)

Comment: Are you saying that inserting `date_trunc(...) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` into column `day` results in a db value with `... +03:00`? The problem is that `date_trunc()` returns `timestamp` and not `timestamptz`, so first convert the result of `date_trunc()` to `timestamp with time zone`, then if necessary add `at time zone 'UTC'`.